Angular - Get route path
I know that it is possible to get the current URL in angular that way : this.router.url, however, what I'm looking for is the path.
I have this in a forum.routes.ts file:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ForumComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Forum' },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ForumListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':forum',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: DiscussionsComponent,
            data: { breadcrumb: 'Forum name' },
          },
          {
            path: 'discussion',
            children: [
              {
                path: 'nouvelle',
                component: NewDiscussionComponent,
                data: { breadcrumb: 'Nouvelle discussion' },
              },
              {
                path: ':discussionId/:discussionTitle',
                component: DiscussionComponent,
                data: { breadcrumb: 'Discussion name' },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

Let's say that my current route is /forum/politique/discussion/87/abcd. The last component is DiscussionComponent. I want the path until there which means something like this: /forum/:forum/discussion/:discussionId/:discussionTitle, is there a way to get this?
I don't want the current route, I want the parameters that form the current route if that makes sense.

Does this answer your question? How to get parameter on Angular2 route in Angular way?

You can use the below property. The activatedRoute has a property call routeConfig which contains a path property which contains the current route path.
...
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productsService: ProductsService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const products = this.productsService.getProducts();
    console.log(this.route.routeConfig.path);  // <- changed here!
    ...

Stackblitz Demo- not by me -> go to /product/101
